# In C++ why a pure function must be virtual?

Tags: c++, function, class, virtual

I have searched on google and here but I can not understand why a pure function in a class must be virtual. I understand maybe it is not very useful declare a "normal function" as pure but I don't think is a nonsense. I mean, the word "pure" is there just to declare an abstract class. Ok, I can not use polymorphism with that pure normal function but the main reason (declare a class as abstract) is reached anyway.
Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have an example class to demonstrate your particular case?

Comment: No. Is just theory. I tried to declare a normal function in an abstract class as pure and I noticed the compile error.

Comment: What I mean is it's usually a good thing to include what you've tried so people can speak to your example. Code + specific errors = better answers.

Comment: Because it would be pointless to do so.

Comment: Probably because C++ doesn't have the concept of 'pure' functions?

Comment: I think, you've fallen into language trap. You can say that Jennifer Aniston is an example of *pure human beauty*, but it doesn't mean you can talk about pure humans.

Comment: @SergeyA Take that back. Jennifer Aniston is a _pure_ human!

Comment: @erip, no one should **ever** mention pure humans. This assumes there are **unpure** humans, and this is what fascist ideologies are based on. There is no such thing as pure humans, since there are no unpure ones.

Comment: @SergeyA Depends on your philosophical subscription. :)

Comment: @SergeyA: That's incorrect. Just because there is no such thing as dry water doesn't mean water isn't wet.

Comment: inb4 what about dry ice yes stop picking apart my hastily chosen analogy

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, too much of grammar for me. I am not a native speaker.

Comment: @SergeyA: Hey, you started this!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, and now I am backpedalling.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Have you thought about dry ice? :)

Comment: @erip: You are a hilarious individual!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no requirement that a pure function be virtual. If you're thinking of the term "pure virtual function", "pure" applies to "virtual" there; the function is purely virtual. It's a different use of the word "pure".

> I mean, the word "pure" is there just to declare an abstract class.

It's not. The reason for declaring a pure virtual function is not to prevent instantiation of the enclosing class; it's to ensure that concrete subclasses implement the method, usually because the abstract class cannot provide a reasonable implementation.

> Ok, I can not use polymorphism with that pure normal function but the main reason (declare a class as abstract) is reached anyway.

If you're looking for a way to declare a class abstract without any pure virtual functions, C++ does not have dedicated syntax for that. The suggestions I've seen are to [declare and implement a pure virtual destructor (you can do that), or to make the constructor protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631685/c-abstract-class-without-pure-virtual-functions) (but making the constructor protected won't make your class pass [`std::is_abstract`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_abstract)). In any case, it wouldn't make much sense to attach the syntax for that to arbitrary member functions; something like `class Foo = 0 { ... };` would make more sense.

Comment: I don't understand. I tried to create a simple class with a normal pure function (for example: void fun() = 0) and the compiler raised an error.

Comment: @andre3312: "= 0" is not the syntax to declare that a function is pure; it's the syntax to declare that a virtual function is purely virtual. Trying to put it on a non-virtual function is like trying to say that a burger is "very food" instead of "very tasty food" or "very unhealthy food".

Comment: *There is no requirement that a pure function be virtual.* Not true. Only `virtual` member functions can be pure.

Comment: @RSahu: "Pure function" refers to [a function whose return value depends only on its parameters, and which produces no side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). There is no requirement that such a function be virtual. You're thinking of pure virtual functions, an entirely unrelated concept.

Comment: @RSahu "Pure functions" are typically what functions in functional languages are referred to. A pure function is a function with no side effects.

Comment: That's not the kind of "pure" the OP is talking about. They are talking about the creation of pure virtual functions using the `= 0;` specifier.

Comment: @RSahu Fair, but your qualm was with the statement that pure functions must be virtual - they don't have to be. Semantics are important. :) It's also hard to understand as a concept because "pure functions" wrt OO _don't exist_.

Comment: @erip, in the context of C++, that's a correct assertion.

Comment: No, it's not. That's like saying C pointers are smart pointers because they're used in a good way. It's conflating two terms that have very different meanings.

Comment: Yes, this is correct answer. Pure function is not a concept which exists in  C++.

Comment: I think this would could much less confusion if people called them by their grammatical name. They're _purely virtual_ functions.

Comment: It's really annoying that you are biased / feel attacked because of the word `pure`. Yes, pure virtual functions _do_ exist in C++, period.

Comment: @GillBates I don't think you understand the argument here.

Comment: @erip, I can see that English is your native language! :) Or you just good at english grammar.

Comment: @SergeyA Not all native speakers have a good grasp of English grammar... trust me. :P

Comment: @erip I do, people are bitching about `pure` as opposed to `purely`, we all know what OP meant and bitching about something like that is childish at best.

Comment: @GillBates No one is arguing that _pure virtual_ functions don't exist. We are arguing that _pure_ functions, in the C++ OO paradigm, do not exist _as described by OP_. `pure functions != "pure functions" != pure virtual functions`

Comment: @erip As I said before, OP obviously meant pure virtual functions as opposed to pure functions. The context gives that away.

Comment: @GillBates The question is about semantics; specifically about a misunderstanding with respect to those regarding "pure functions." To address the question, we must define "pure functions." The resolution to this question is simply that "pure functions" don't exist in C++. The confusion lies in that pure describes virtual, not function - hence my choice of calling them _purely virtual_ functions.

Comment: @erip Yes I understand your point but from the following passage "Ok, I can not use polymorphism with that pure normal function but the main reason (declare a class as abstract) is reached anyway" You can clearly tell OP means purely virtual functions. My rant wasn't necessarily against you but rather to the people that purposely took the word `pure` out of context. There was no confusion OP was talking about `purely virtual` functions.

Comment: @GillBates: If the OP really was talking about purely virtual functions, then the question in the title is nonsense. It becomes, "In C++, why must a purely virtual function be virtual?"

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Well yeah, it can be. I never said it wasn't but judging from " but the main reason (declare a class as abstract)" it's definitely not about pure functions.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason you'd want to have a "pure function" is to make sure subclasses that inherit from this class define an implementation of this function. If you would allow pure functions to be non-virtual and thus not being able to be overriden they are basically pointless to have.

Comment: But I can override a function not virtual.

Comment: I think, this answer undully assumes that 'pure' functions exist.

Comment: @andre3312, you can. However, the function call won't be dispatched to the derived class implementation if the call is made through a base class pointer or object.

Comment: @SergeyA No, I'm saying that a pure function that has no `virtual` wouldn't make sense, `pure virtual` functions exist yes. Or `pure virtual` methods if you want to get specific.

Comment: Again, to have 'pure' functions, language should have 'unpure' functions. Every function in C++ is a pure function, because non of them are unpure.

Comment: @SergeyA Not sure if I understand you here, a function that does not contain a body and has `= 0` after it's signature is a pure virtual function. Once that does not is not a pure virtual function. What do you mean with "every function in C++ is a pure function because non of them are unpure" ?

Comment: What I am saying is that C++ doesn't have the concept of pure functions. Period. They do not exist.

Comment: @SergeyA Then how would you name a function that has `= 0` after it and is vritual ? `equals null functions` ?

Comment: No, those are pure virtual function. Where *pure* relates to *virtual*, not *function*. See my comments under the question and the answer from @user2357112

Comment: @SergeyA That's what I _literally_ just said, you're just being silly now. "Not sure if I understand you here, a function that does not contain a body and has = 0 after it's signature is a pure virtual function." to which you respond : "No, those are pure virtual function" What?

Comment: No is for 'equals null functions'. Last time. While **pure virtual functions** exist, **pure functions** do not.

Comment: Yeah nvm, not worth arguing over.

Comment: @andre3312: _"But I can override a function not virtual."_ No, you can't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Are you telling I can't override a function in a derived class?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Maybe it is not a good practice but it is not prohibited

Comment: @andre3312: No, it's literally impossible. You're mistaking _name hiding_ for overriding.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Please have a look at this. Question number 10 of the link. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#redefining-nonvirtuals.

Comment: @andre3312: That's not actually overriding. The word "override" is in quotes there to indicate that, but really they should have avoided it altogether. Remember, a collaboratively edited Wiki on the internet is not authoritative; the ISO standard is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111722/discussion-between-andre3312-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).